# Randomizing f-curve offsets for many objects?

Tags: animation, fcurves

[image]I have a scene where I need to light up spheres with emission in a cyclic pattern, where they oscillate between a high point of brightness and a low one.

I want to control the oscilation as I please, the frequency or the limits of the values of brightness. So I connected a value node to the emission node and added a sine f-curve to that value. This gives me precise control over the oscillation, however they all do the animation simultaneously. There is an offset option in the f-curve modifier menu, but I could not utilise it for my purpose.

How can I offset this effect for around 1000 balls, so they all seem flickering randomly? I just want those sine curves for each object randomly offsetted.

Edit:

I also thought maybe animation nodes could be helpful, and I'm not still sure if it could be used to solve my specific problem; but animation nodes system looks very confusing and I'm absolute beginner there. Therefore it did not lead anywhere. Can it be used for this purpose, and if so, how?

[image]

Comment: Any other route of solution with instructions, to the main problem, is welcome too.

Comment: you can use a python script for this kind of task

Comment: I cannot even write a single line of phyton or any other code. Can anyone provide such a snippet, if it is relatively simple? I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: If u provide your blend file - I will write the script

Comment: open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions...but only if thibserts answer doesn't satisfy you...

Comment: I've added the blend file, you can see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a F-Curve, you could use a Shader Node based solution, using the Random output of the Object Info node as an offset.

[image]

"frequency", "amplitude" and "minimum" are just Value Nodes, I added them for clarity. You can control your sine signal with them. They are *quite* equivalent to "phase multiplier", "amplitude" and "value offset" in the FCurve sine modifier.

"frame driver" is a value node with a Driver : simply type "#frame"  in the field ; it will output the number of the current frame.

Object Info/Random output a random value for each object, between 0.0 and 1.0.

Blue nodes are Math nodes which perform this operation : **(sine(frame/frequency + random)+1) * amplitude + minimum**

Comment: It could be more elegant (and convenient) to keep your FCurve and somehow mix it with the Random value, but I hadn't be able to figure how. Also, you can add some math node to fit your needs (ie, add a minimum or maximum value)

Comment: In fact, you SHOULD add a minimum vale (plug a "greater than : 0") just before the Emission node. In my screenshot, you get negative values for Emission Strength, which leads to quite inacurate results

Comment: Even if added the greater than node, it still gives black for some balls. And I could not figure it out how to sex maximum and minimum brightness in this setup, nor how quickly they would oscillate between these values. Can you please explain how to achieve these with your setup?

Comment: I updated my answer with a better solution. sine(x)+1 gives values between 0 and 2, so no negative values (and more sinusoidal than a "greater than 0"). "Minimum" is the lower Strength any light can have. With amplitude = 1 and minimum = 0.3, you should have a signal similar as the one you shown in your screenshot.

Comment: I've added a multiply math node after random output, before it connects to add node which connects to sine node. That seemed to gave me more control. I'm still checking for the desired effect. If no new problems arise, it seems like your node system did solve my problem. Thanks so much in advance.